# Consistently and reliably use Screen Sharing with Back to My Mac

Tags: macbook, screen-sharing, icloud

I'm trying to connect to my MacBook Pro at home, and it works only 50% of the time. I want to use Screen Sharing as you can copy-paste, cmd-tab, scroll properly and other things I haven't seen in other products like TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Chrome remote desktop? It's a great product, and works from different operating systems, so you should be able to connect to the Mac from either Windows / Linux or another Mac. It's fairly quick as well, I use it to connect to my mac mini from an Ubuntu laptop at work.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en